Inverse Algorithm for partial bit reverse
I have written this algorithm to perform a stable bit revere sorting considering only n least significant bits:
// Function to compute bit-reversed index
auto bit_reversed_index(int index, uint8_t levels) -> int
{
    int rev = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < levels; ++i) {
        rev <<= 1;
        rev |= (index & 1);
        index >>= 1;
    }
    return rev;
}

auto partial_bit_reverse(vec& signal, size_t n, uint8_t levels) -> void
{
   std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> temp(n);


    // Compute bit-reversed indices and store in a temporary vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int rev_index = bit_reversed_index(i, levels);
        temp[i] = {rev_index, signal[i]};
    }

    // Sort the temporary vector by bit-reversed indices, preserving original order on ties
    std::stable_sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), [](const std::pair<int, double>& a, const std::pair<int, double>& b) {
        return a.first < b.first;
    });

    // Copy sorted values back to the original signal vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        signal[i] = temp[i].second;
    }
}

some example for this:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  -> 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8 number of levels: 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  -> 1 5 3 7 2 6 4 8 number of levels: 2

I now need to recover the original permutation given the partial bit reversed one

Sorting is irreversible (more than one input produces the same output thus it's impossible to determine input by output alone). Do you have any additional data?

I have the number of bits considered to perform the initial ordering

On the off chance that you're trying to implement the bit-reversal permutation (for eg FFT), I'll just note that this code does not perform it. If it did, then it would be its own inverse, and also it's a well-studied permutation that can be implemented much more efficiently than this.

An observation must be made, that output from bit_reversed_index when iterating incrementally from 0 to some n will be a cycle with length 1<<levels.
For example for bit_reversed_index(i, 1) (where i is index from 0 to some n)
0
1
0 < next cycle begins
1
.

Or for bit_reversed_index(i, 3)
000
100
010
110
001
101
011
111
000 < next cycle begins
100
.

We also need to examine how the cycle translate to indexes during stable sorting.
00 -----|
10 -----|-----|
11 -----|-----|-|
01 -----|---| | |
00 -----|-| | | | 
        ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
Output: 0 0 1 2 3

What's also important is that calling bit_reversed_index on cycle index (index since beginning of cycle) will return levels most significant bits of original index.
With this information in mind, since we know n, we can calculate exactly how many cycles occurred and at what index in the stable sort (stable_index) is our reversed index. Then all we have to do is to call bit_reversed_index on that stable_index and offset it by length of all cycles that occurred beforehand (stable_index_nr*cycle_length). Calculation is trivial, thus I will skip to implementation.
auto reveresed_bit_reveresed_index(int rev_index, uint8_t levels, size_t n) -> int
{
    int cycle_length = 1<<levels, cycle_count = n/cycle_length, cycle_offset = n%cycle_length;

    // Calculate index within stable sort
    int stable_index;
    if(rev_index < (cycle_count+1)*(cycle_offset))
        stable_index = rev_index/(cycle_count+1);
    else
        stable_index = (rev_index-cycle_offset)/(cycle_count);

    // Calculate how many same indexes occurred before
    int stable_index_nr = stable_index*cycle_count;
    if(cycle_offset < stable_index)
        stable_index_nr += cycle_offset;
    else
        stable_index_nr += stable_index;

    stable_index_nr = rev_index - stable_index_nr;

    // Extract the old index
    return bit_reversed_index(stable_index, levels)+(stable_index_nr*cycle_length);
}

Outputs from this function must also be stable sorted and then stored into a new vector, just like in partial_bit_reverse, since for n < (1<<levels), extracted indexes will be offset, by some value.
For example the output might be {4, 1, 7}, where after sorting we get {1, 4, 7}, where 1 refers to index 0, 4 to index 1, 7 to index 2 etc.
auto partial_bit_unreverse(vec& signal, size_t n, uint8_t levels) -> void
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> temp(n);

    // Compute bit-unreversed indices and store in a temporary vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int org_index = reversed_bit_reversed_index(i, levels);
        temp[i] = {org_index, signal[i]};
    }

    // Sort the temporary vector by reversed-bit-reversed indices, preserving original order on ties
    std::stable_sort(temp.begin(), temp.end(), [](const std::pair<int, double>& a, const std::pair<int, double>& b) {
        return a.first < b.first;
    });

    // Copy sorted values back to the original signal vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        signal[i] = temp[i].second;
    }
}

